# Can not read all cookies of a request in asp.net core

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0, httpcookie

I'm coding in asp.net core mvc. My problem is a set somes cookie by javascript, but in the asp.net core mvc controller, I cannot retrieve value of a specific key I had set before. And then I try counting number of key are existing in the cookie list.

```
string strCart = Request.Cookies.Count().ToString();
```

The output is 2 despite It must be 3 and the key I want to get is missing in `Request.Cookies`

Edit:
This is the js code

```
function SetCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays,cpath) 
{ 
  let d = new Date(); 
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/" + cpath;
}
```

it works on directly with php but got the problem with asp.net core

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the cookies in javascript? Also, have you confirmed the cookies exist by checking them in the browser?

Comment: Plase edit additional code into the Question. It did it for you this time.

Comment: @LemuelBotha It all exist in the browser when I check it.

Comment: @Christopher I have editted.

Comment: The input/how you call it might be important. After all if exdays is 0, the Expiration date will be "now". Meaning it is collected before it could be send.

Comment: @Christopher I have checked, I have 2 cookie with the same expday and not expired. But I can get only one and the other is missing. Let me specify, the one missing has value is a json string. Is the problem comes with that?

Comment: My missing cookie is cart=[{"id":1,"qty":6}]. Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: For now, I figured out the cookie with json string value can't be discovered by asp.net core. Can someone give me keywords about this?

Comment: If you look at hte ASP.Net Page Lifecycle, you will notice tons of automagics mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) | Any one of those could have caused your Cookie (wich was not set from Server code) to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net, you do not do a lot of level stuff. Stuff like creating a cookie is right on the level you do not usually do. ASP.Net [has a lot of Automagics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)) to make programming here easier. A automagic for storing and retreiving a Session ID via cookies and Link values is among them. That code might easily swallow a cookie that was creatred client side, without the server knowing of it. It could even be a active security measure - allowing any random value to be set by the Client Request has prooven troublesome time and time again.

Based on one comment, this is what you expect: `cart=[{"id":1,"qty":6}]`. So I am going to guess for a Online Shop. Now data like a cart *really* does not belong onto the client side. It is too easy for a attacker to break your code by throwing unexpected values at you. Never trust user Input. And with any networking, that distrust should be cubed.

I think when they allow you to use the cart before you logged in, what they do is give you a Session ID regardless of login state. Usually you only get SID's after a login. But Onlineshops tend to give ones to everyone that does not send one along with the Request. It is SID's for everyone. If they later do log in or create a account, it is just a mater of linking the session to the account, copying the cart on the server side or something similar like that.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I 've found solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for supporting me, now I've found the problem of my code. The problem is when setting cookie value I forgot to escape the string's character. In php or js, it is accepted, but c# is strong type language and c# uses double quote to determine a string so the json string has character that cause the conflict. After that, the  result is the specific cookie is missing